# Set the colorbar in function of data

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, colorbar

I have a question about matplotlib and colorbar. I have in my project lots of heatmaps. Assuming my array is the result from a divide between 2 arrays.

For example (in order to visualize the problem) :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

array_1 = A/B    # A and B are 2 arrays, same shape etc ..
array_2 = C/D    # C and D are 2 arrays, same shape etc ..

##################################
# Representation with matplotlib #
##################################

fig_step1 = ax1.imshow(array_1, interpolation='nearest')
fig1.colorbar(fig_step1,ax=ax1)
ax1.set_xlabel("X (arcmin)")
ax1.set_ylabel("Y (arcmin)")
ax1.set_title("array number 1")

fig_step2 = ax2.imshow(array_2, interpolation='nearest')
fig1.colorbar(fig_step2,ax=ax2)
ax2.set_xlabel("X (arcmin)")
ax2.set_ylabel("Y (arcmin)")
ax2.set_title("array number 2")
```

==> But, even if the divide is good for 99% of my data and I get the mean from array_1 and array_2 arount the value 1 for example. Sometimes I have few points (1%) where the result between A/B is 1000000 for example and make my colorbar wrong.

==> How it's possible to play with the colorbar in order to print in my heatmap only points between [0;1] ? That's to say, to have a dynamic colorbar ?

I apologize for my very bad English :/

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that there are two solutions: either set the `vmin` and `vmax` arguments of `imshow`, or mask the invalid values in your arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

A = np.random.random((20,20))
B = np.random.random((20,20))

array_1 = A/B    # A and B are 2 arrays, same shape etc ..

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1  = plt.subplot(121)
fig_step1 = ax1.imshow(array_1, interpolation='nearest')
fig1.colorbar(fig_step1,ax=ax1)
ax1.set_xlabel("X (arcmin)")
ax1.set_ylabel("Y (arcmin)")
ax1.set_title("Without limits")

ax2  = plt.subplot(122)
fig_step2 = ax2.imshow(array_1, interpolation='nearest', vmin=0, vmax=1)
fig1.colorbar(fig_step2, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_xlabel("X (arcmin)")
ax2.set_ylabel("Y (arcmin)")
ax2.set_title("With limits")
```

Which results in:
[image]

Or, if you want to mask the invalid values (assuming that everything larger than 1 is invalid):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

A = np.random.random((20,20))
B = np.random.random((20,20))

array_1 = A/B    # A and B are 2 arrays, same shape etc ..

# Mask the array with the required limits
array_1 = np.ma.masked_where(array_1 > 1, array_1)

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1  = plt.subplot(111)
fig_step1 = ax1.imshow(array_1, interpolation='nearest')
fig1.colorbar(fig_step1,ax=ax1)
ax1.set_xlabel("X (arcmin)")
ax1.set_ylabel("Y (arcmin)")
ax1.set_title("No limits, but masked")
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: Thanks to your answer. I will try the solution with `vmin` and `vmax`. The mask is not possible in my case. Even if I tried with `np.ma.masked.greater`